# wkwebview - display image from documents directory into local html

Tags: html, ios11, wkwebview

I have an app with downloaded images to be displayed in local html. I am still using `Objective-C` because this app is 4 years old.
When first launch the app, it will download the images and other dynamic content (which I check, it is in Documents/content/ directory).

I have this code to get the content location:

```
NSString *contentBasePath = [app.contentManager contentBasePath];
```

which I get:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4AFD30E2-F4F7-405A-9FE9-1857EEC11CC7/Documents/content

Then I have a few html pages that will call the downloaded images dynamically:

```
<div class="box-round benefits-thumbnail" style="background-image:url('file://{{../contentBasePath}}/{{filename}}');"></div>
```

Which I check, `{{../contentBasePath}}` will get:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4AFD30E2-F4F7-405A-9FE9-1857EEC11CC7/Documents/content

and `{{filename}}` will get

```
example.jpg
```

which is all correct.

All this works with `uiwebview`. However I need to use `wkwebview`, the image did not show up.

I tried:

```
<div class="box-round benefits-thumbnail" style="background-image:url('{{../contentBasePath}}/{{filename}}');"></div>
```

and it still not working.

I googled and read around and it seems like `wkwebview` do not allow absolute path. so I tried as per this suggest:

```
[_webConfig.preferences  setValue:@YES forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
```

and still not working.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: did you find any work around ?? I have a similar issue in swift , images come in simulator but not in real device.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a limitation of the WebKit. As a workaround, you can write the HTML contents into a file in the documents directory and load it using `[webView loadFileURL:fileUrl allowingReadAccessToURL:dirUrl]`

Link to docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl

Comment: I end up copy the whole folder into temp folder and that will work.

Comment: Please note that things will work the resources are in your bundle directory. Only the documents directory has this problem.

Comment: @sooon how you did can you help me out with the steps

Answer (score 0):

The files must be in the document directory.

I implemented the following to retrieve a document:

```
    let documentDirUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let fileNameWithExtension = "IMG_0002.PNG"
    let indexFileUrl = documentDirUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileNameWithExtension)
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: indexFileUrl.path) {
        webView.loadFileURL(indexFileUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: documentDirUrl)
    }
```

Comment: I have the base url where image is stored in documents directory n I have HTML which has the image extension how can load it in WKWebview 
Can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800637/ios-13-swift-5-wkwebview-display-image-from-documents-directory-into-local-htm

Comment: @iMinion my solution is in objective c but i guess the method should be the same. in my case, i download everything from web, so i have to move all the downloaded content including images into temp folder everytime the page is loaded. but maybe swift will have some more elegant solution than this. hope this help one way or another. good luck.

Comment: @sooon did u had just one image to display at a time or couple of if u can tell how you managed that.

Comment: it is basically a html product page, so multiple images, if i remember correctly, when we download the files, it will all go to Documents/content/ folder. then i just use for loop to copy the files in that folder one by one into temp folder, then my html load the image from the temp folder.

Comment: another point to note, it is temp folder, that means whenever the device is running low or require more memory, it will delete off your contents. so i have a download function called everytime user launch the app. not the most effective way of handling I know, but it get the jobs done.

Comment: by the way, my code is in objective c, so my code would be helpful for you.

Comment: @sooon I have this  
I get have this as HTML
"<body>\n<p><img src=\"images/d35fb6a3-8a21-4196-9616-ad2c6db60669/fd21b894-38c0-42c5-aa69-a938abe40e4b2467857252325869136.png\"></p>\n<p><img src=\"images/d35fb6a3-8a21-4196-9616-ad2c6db60669/c927a2a6-4ef0-481d-b27d-525cec7ed3814195490571216387044.png\"><br></p>\n</body></html>"  and the resources are there in documents directory how can I render this HTML with cached  resources in WKWebview