# iOS 13 Swift 5 wkwebview - display image from documents directory into wkwebview real device

Tags: html, xcode, wkwebview, ios13, swift5

I have an app with downloaded images to be displayed in local html in WKWEBVIEW. Everything is working fine but it is not showing image on iPhone device

the html  is

"\n

<img src="images/d35fb6a3-8a21-4196-9616-ad2c6db60669/fd21b894-38c0-42c5-aa69-a938abe40e4b2467857252325869136.png">

\n

<img src="images/d35fb6a3-8a21-4196-9616-ad2c6db60669/c927a2a6-4ef0-481d-b27d-525cec7ed3814195490571216387044.png">

\n"

matching to this HTML it is to be displayed in a wkwebview which gets displayed perfectly on simulator with the following code

```
let baseURL = Functions.FileIO.contentFolderURL()
```

```
static func contentFolderURL() -> URL? {
            guard let folderURL = DataManager.shared.applicationDocumentsURL?.appendingPathComponent("content") else {
                return nil
            }
            
            do {
                let properties = try (folderURL as NSURL).resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey])
                if let isDirectory = properties[URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey] as? Bool , isDirectory == false {
                    return nil
                }
            } catch let error as NSError where error.code != NSFileReadNoSuchFileError {
                return nil
            } catch {
                // No folder, so we create it.
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folderURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                } catch {
                    return nil
                }
            }
            
            return folderURL
        }
```

and then finally displaying

baseURL comes to be

> Optional   ▿ some :
> file:///Users/paza/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D2204E03-8A8F-4EF4-8924-683CF519DD19/data/Containers/Data/Application/E4ED56CF-B247-4471-9F9B-23384FD6D6B3/Documents/content/
> - _url : file:///Users/paza/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D2204E03-8A8F-4EF4-8924-683CF519DD19/data/Containers/Data/Application/E4ED56CF-B247-4471-9F9B-23384FD6D6B3/Documents/content/

```
self.webView?.loadHTMLString(HTML, baseURL: baseURL)
```

working in simulator below does not work in Device

[image]

as [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838445/3455426[](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838445/3455426%5B) ][2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838445/3455426)

suggested I tried

```
self.webView?.loadFileURL(baseURL, allowingReadAccessTo: baseURL)
```

but the result this comes blank on real device
[image]

any leads will be appreciated , Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you pls check this link?. Hope it will work for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803341/swift-wkwebview-loading-local-file-not-working-on-a-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WKWebview if we have to show HTML with Cached resources  ,firstly we have to save the html string in HTML file in documents directory.

make sure ur cached resources path and the path of HTML file  are same also , the cached resources are identified by the lastPathComponent only .

So the fault was the HTML which should have been

```
let HTML = "<html><body>\n<p><img src=\"fd21b894-38c0-42c5-aa69-a938abe40e4b2467857252325869136.png\"></p>\n<p><img src=\"c927a2a6-4ef0-481d-b27d-525cec7ed3814195490571216387044.png\"><br></p>\n</body></html>"
```

Specifically the last path component should be there .

Also I followed
https://en.it1352.com/article/9f185d4d185243cc92128148443ca660.html
here the explanation is almost perfect , I just saved in documents directory for swift.